# How "this" keyword actually works inside Intent constructor arguement?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, this

Intent construcotr's arguements require object of Context class but down here inside this code I am passing "this" which means object of MainActivity class object. How it works? because it requires Context Class instance but i am passing MainActivity's instance.

```
const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstApp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun sendMessage(view: View){
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent =Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply{  
// if I use MainActivity() instead of this , gives me error  
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Here, `this` means MainActivity's instance, but if I use `MainActivity()` instead of `this` it gives me error. Whereas `this` and `MainActivity()` are same thing here.

Answer (score 2):

In Android `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Application` all extends `Context`. So you can pass them in place of `Context`.

You can see all the class that an `Activity` class extends [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity).

Comment: ya! I understand, but my question is if  MainActivity class extends Context class, then why we can't use MainActivity() direcly in place of "this", inside Intent() arguement. Whereas they both mean same here.

Comment: You can use `MainActivity()` instead of this as the first parameter to the `Intent()` and the IDE won't show any error because it's correct as per Java syntax. However, in Android we don't create an instance of the `Activity` manually and instead pass an Intent with the details of the `Activity` to start to the Android frame work which creates an activity and calls `onCreate()` and other life-cycle methods on the newly created instance.

Comment: Just additional to @Saran Sankaran.

You could also use:
`MainActivity.this`

Comment: @sparshgoyal `this` is a reference to the instance within which it is used, so it doesn't create any new instance.

Comment: @sparshgoyal this is the instance of the Activity (or `MainActivity` in your case). Its not a instance created by you, its a instance created by OS. But you need not worry about that for now. `MainActivity()` is not something you should pass you should be passing `this` or  `MainActivity.this` for your current activity. Hope this resolves your doubt. :)

Comment: Why not mark this as the answer then? some one in future will definitely find this answer useful